# Can't include the pong game on one of two screens - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

That's my error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'move'
```

I have been searching, looking kivy videos and trying a lot of things but I can't get the ball of the Pong Game tutorial to work on my GameScreen when I press Play in StartScreen.
Sometimes i don't get an error but only when the game isn't on the screen. The app then works normally and the ball (snake snaky) does show on the right SnakeWidget widget, but i can't change its position even with typing the exact position.

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from random import randint

class InfoWidget(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)


class Snake(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class SnakeWidget(Widget):
    snaky = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SnakeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def begin(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.snaky.center = self.center
        self.snaky.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.snaky.move()

class InfoWidget(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

class StartScreen(Screen): 
    snake_widget = SnakeWidget()
    Clock.schedule_interval(snake_widget.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Main2App(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv("main2.kv")
        return RootScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main2App().run()
```

.kv file:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<StartScreen>:
    name: "start"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "lights.png"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: "play"
            background_color: 0.012, 0.227, 0.11, 0.1
            text: "Play!"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.3
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            font_size: 70
            on_release: root.current = 'game'; snake_widget.begin()
        Button:
            id: "how"
            background_color: 0.012, 0.227, 0.11, 0.1
            text: "How to play"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.3}
            font_size: 40

<GameScreen>:
    name: "game"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "lights.png"
    FloatLayout:
        SnakeWidget:
        InfoWidget: 
        Button:
            id: menu
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.8,"y":0.9}
            background_color: 0.012, 0.227, 0.11,0.3
            text: "Menu"
            font_size: 17
            on_release: root.manager.current  = "start"
        Button: 
            id: levo
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.8,"y":0}
            background_color: 0.012, 0.227, 0.11,0.3
            text: "<"
            font_size: 20
        Button: 
            id: desno
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.9,"y":0}
            background_color: 0.012, 0.227, 0.11,0.3
            text: ">"
            font_size: 20

<Snake>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: 40, 40
            source: "snaky.png"

<SnakeWidget>:
    id: snake_widget
    snaky: snake
    size_hint: 0.797, 1
    pos_hint: {"x": 0,"center_y":0.5}
    canvas: 
        Color: 
            rgba: 1,1,1,0.07
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Snake: 
        id: snake
        center: self.parent.center

<InfoWidget>:
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.799
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.8014,"y":0.101}
    canvas.before: 
        Color:
            rgba: 0.010, 0.227, 0.17, 0.005
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    Label: 
        canvas.before: 
            Color:
                rgba: 0.010, 0.227, 0.17, 0.005
            Rectangle:
                size: root.parent.width*0.192, root.parent.height*0.06
                pos: root.parent.width*0.805, root.parent.height*0.837
        id: "result"
        text: "Result:"
        font_size: 17
        pos: root.parent.width*0.79, root.parent.height*0.78

    Label:
        canvas.before: 
            Color:
                rgba: 0.012, 0.227, 0.15, 0.005
            Rectangle:
                size: root.parent.width*0.192, root.parent.height*0.06
                pos: root.parent.width*0.805, root.parent.height*0.77
        id: "record"
        text: "Record:"
        font_size: 17
        pos: root.parent.width*0.79, root.parent.height*0.72



<RootScreen>:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: FadeTransition() 
    StartScreen:
        name: "start"
    GameScreen:
        name: "game"
```

Sorry for all the code, but I really don't know what to try anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In line 35,

```
class SnakeWidget(Widget):
    snaky = ObjectProperty(Snake())
```

`Snaky` should be an instance of `Snake`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something Like this:

.py is here...

```
class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

    #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
        self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

    #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('t6.kv')
        return Manager(transition=WipeTransition())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

and .kv is here...

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager


    Screen:
        name: 'home'
        Button:
            text: 'Play Ping Pong'
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            font_size: 100
            text_size: self.size
            on_release: root.current = 'game';game.serve_ball()

    Screen:
        name: 'game'
        PongGame:
            id: game
```

Hope this would help...